# Multiline UIButton with each line truncated independently

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel, truncate

I'm trying to make a multiline button by subclassing UIButton. To avoid drawing two custom `UILabel` (I'm still pretty new to Swift/Xcode), I'm using attributed strings for the existing `UILabel` and splitting lines with a new line character, like so:

```
func prepareAttributedTitle(_ primaryTitle: String = "", _ secondaryTitle: String = "") {
    let title = NSMutableAttributedString()
    let first = NSAttributedString(string: primaryTitle, attributes: [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: tintColor,
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize, weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)
    ])
    let newLine = NSAttributedString(string: "\n")
    let second = NSAttributedString(string: secondaryTitle, attributes: [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: tintColor.withAlphaComponent(0.75),
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.smallSystemFontSize)
    ])

    title.append(first)
    title.append(newLine)
    title.append(second)

    setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
}
```

And the result is (sorry, I don't have enough rep to post images):

```
| This is the long first |
| line                   |
| Secondary line         |
```

However, I'd like to truncate lines independently, like this:

```
| This is the long fi... |
| Secondary line         |
```

Is there a way to do this without using two custom UILabels?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single `UILabel` does not support what you need. You will have to use two single-line labels each set with tail truncation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question with what worked for me. Here's my subclass of UIButton, but keep in mind I'm not an experienced developer. There's also some styling and support for the tint color:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable

class FilterButton: UIButton {

    let primaryLabel = UILabel()
    let secondaryLabel = UILabel()

    @IBInspectable var primaryTitle = "" {
        didSet {
            primaryLabel.text = primaryTitle
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var secondaryTitle = "" {
        didSet {
            secondaryLabel.text = secondaryTitle
        }
    }

    // MARK: Initialization
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        primaryTitle = "Primary title"
        secondaryTitle = "Secondary title"
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        // Force left alignment (FIXME: Use user language direction)
        contentHorizontalAlignment = .left

        // Set some padding and styling
        contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 10, bottom: 5, right: 10)
        layer.cornerRadius = 5
        layer.borderWidth = 1

        // Hide button original label
        titleLabel?.isHidden = true

        // Prepare the primary label
        primaryLabel.frame = CGRect(x: contentEdgeInsets.left,
                                    y: contentEdgeInsets.top,
                                width: frame.width - contentEdgeInsets.left - contentEdgeInsets.right,
                                height: (frame.height - contentEdgeInsets.top - contentEdgeInsets.bottom) / 2)
        primaryLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)
        primaryLabel.textColor = tintColor
        // primaryLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.green // For debugging
        primaryLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle // Truncate first line
        primaryLabel.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
        addSubview(primaryLabel)

        // Prepare the secondary label
        secondaryLabel.frame = CGRect(x: contentEdgeInsets.left,
                                      y: contentEdgeInsets.top + primaryLabel.frame.height,
                                  width: frame.width - contentEdgeInsets.left - contentEdgeInsets.right,
                                 height: (frame.height - contentEdgeInsets.top - contentEdgeInsets.bottom) / 2)
        secondaryLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.smallSystemFontSize)
        secondaryLabel.textColor = tintColor.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
        // secondaryLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow // For debugging
        secondaryLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle // Truncate second line
        secondaryLabel.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
        addSubview(secondaryLabel)

        primaryLabel.text = primaryTitle
        secondaryLabel.text = secondaryTitle
    }

    // Support tint color
    override func tintColorDidChange() {
        super.tintColorDidChange()
        layer.borderColor = tintColor.cgColor
        layer.backgroundColor = tintColor.withAlphaComponent(0.05).cgColor

        primaryLabel.textColor = tintColor
        secondaryLabel.textColor = tintColor.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
    }
}
```